# How to get the label of textbox implemented using form helper in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

For example :

```
 <?php

 ................

  //in my view
 echo $form->input('Model.field', array('label' => 'The label', 'id'=>'txtID'));
 $valueOfLabel = ??????? // how to get the label text which is 'The label'
 .................
  ?>
```

i want to get the "The label" which is the label of the inputbox and store it to a php variable

How can i get it?
Is it possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks :D

Comment: What do you mean *get* it's label value?

Comment: i want to get/retrieve the value of the label which is the 'The label'..

Comment: is @PawelMysior answer what you're looking for? If not can you please clarify with a use case?

Comment: no, ive edited my post, please see it
thanks for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're setting the label yourself as you're showing in the question, then Pawel's answer is correct. Save the value in a variable yourself.

If you're interested in the auto-generated label for a field, this information is not saved anywhere (which is why you can't "get the value"), it's simply output. You could regenerate it using `Inflector::humanize('fieldname')`, which is what the FormHelper uses internally.

<sub>You *could* get the output using output buffering and parse it to extract the output value, but if you're actually doing that, you're insane! Go with Pawel's answer! :-P</sub>

Comment: thanks for repyling... so i guess i really cannot get the auto-generated label for a field.... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$whatever = 'The label';
echo $form->input('Model.field', array('label' => $whatever, 'id'=>'txtID'));
```

?

Comment: thank you for answering but this is not what i mean..
i want


          echo $form->input('Model.field', array('label' => $whatever, 'id'=>'txtID'));
          $whatever = ????? //how to get the label -> 'The label'

Comment: Really don't know what it is that you're trying to achieve. Try to explain.

Comment: hmmm.. so sorry...
ok...
(i assume that you already have experience in form helpers in cakePHP)
so in my code, i have echo " echo $form->input('Model.field', array('label' => 'The label', 'id'=>'txtID'));" ................
and it displays a textbox...
now what i want is to get that text 'The label' which is an attribute of the $form->input code.....

Comment: @Bigs It's not an *attribute*, it's a *parameter*. Pawel already explained the only way to keep it.

Comment: Do you want to get the text `The label`, or the whole label tag (as in `<label for="ModelField">The label</label>`? If it's the first option - see the above code. If it's the second, well... for what? What to you plan to do with it?

Comment: i want to get the text 'The label' and not the tag..
I want to get that because im planning to use it in an if statement or condition

Comment: the code above is not the logic i want...
the label of the textbox changes whenever there is user interaction(using javascript)
thats why i want to get it and use it in an if statement so that i can perform a certain actions..... so sorry for my newbie question
thaks for replying

Comment: Did it really have to take you 5 hours to write that it changes dynamically? That "sort of" important. If it changes using javascript you cannot use it in php. Just edit the question with the whole code and what exactly it is that you're trying to achieve, using the label for an "if" statement doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Bogs More than that though, **never use UI elements for code logic!** You have code somewhere that decides which label should be displayed. Use *that* logic. Don't hang further logic on what the label is. Labels are *just output*, you'll probably change it a few times, fix the spelling, or, god forbid, translate it. You do not want to have *logic* that'll break hanging on the value of *a label*!

Comment: Thanks everyone for repyling. Im so ashamed because i asked a super noob question... i'll remember that Mr.deceze...
I guess ill change my code and find another way..
thanks :D